# Carrying a conditional formatting formula from one reference row to another reference row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have month wise reference row to use conditional formatting. They are arranged like Target Date as reference row and actual dates are arranged below the target date suppose it contains the actual date for 10 orders in 10 different columns.

Now I have set conditional formatting in this situation against the reference column. Now below the first Month, for the next month the data are arranged like first month. Now the question is when I copy the conditional formatting from the firstly used rule to the next month using format painter, it considers the first month's reference row rather then second month's reference row.

In this situation I have to change the formula for second month's reference row which is much time consuming and irritating also. How can I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your first target date is in cell B2 and your actual dates are in the range B3:B5.  You can use the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option to apply the conditional format.  I guess that you've selected one of the actual dates, and used a formula like `=$B$3>$B$2` to highlight late dates.

If you build the formula by selecting the cells, by default it will use absolute references ($ signs in the address), so that when you copy the conditional format to the rest of the range, the formatting still depends on the value in B3, not B4 or B5. You need to use relative references instead.

To fix this, highlight the cell you applied the conditional formatting to first, choose "Conditional Formatting" from the Home ribbon tab, and click "Manage rules..." Double-click on the faulty rule to edit it, click in the formula and press F2 to enable editing, then delete some of the $ signs from the cell addresses to makes the cell references relative.

It looks like you need a formula like `=B3>B$2`.  This fixes the absolute reference as row 2, but allows you to copy the formatting to other cells in column B.  All the column references are relative, if you copy this formatting to Column C, it will use cell C2 as the reference.

The format above can be applied directly to a single month's data, but if you try to add different months, with different target dates, in the same column, it will still use the original target date from cell B2.

To fix this problem, start by entering the second month's data in column C, next to the first month.  If you enter the second target date in cell C2, and some actual dates in C3:C5, you should be able to copy the formatting from column B and have it work as intended.  Once you have done the formatting in column C, you can drag and drop those cells to wherever you need them for the format of your report (e.g. to further down column B).  You can then add or delete cells to the second month's list as necessary, and copy and paste the formatting for that month.

Comment: This is ok for taget date "Row 2" to actual date "Row 3". If the target date for one month is in row 2 and actual date lies in row 3,4,5. Then I have used my conditional formatting rules like B$2>B3 to make it happen for all 3,4,5 rows. And for the another month target date in row 6 and the actual date lies in row 7,8,9,10,11. Now when I copy the rule used for first target row to another it appears like B$2>B7 instead of B$6>B7 for 7,8,9,10,11 rows. Then I have to manually edit the formula to make it active for the next month like B$6>B7. Is there any way to make it dynamic? Thanks

Comment: I see what you mean now.  I've edited my answer to address your comment.